# Why does the escaped prisoner not return with help?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw

In the end of the movie, Lawrence Gordon (the surgeon) cuts his feet and goes to get help. The movie then ends with Adam (the photographer) getting locked up in the room by the villain. So why does the surgeon not return with help? Does he get killed because he exceeded the time?

Comment: Would you want to go back?

Comment: Get the police!!

Comment: Haha ... I was just playing a little there. I would bet this is one of those situations where everyone here would have to say "***Because it's in the script!***"

Comment: I think the surgeon gets killed. After all he was supposed to accomplish the task by 6 am which he didnt.

Answer (score 6):

Spoilers for Saw 3D ahead:

> After Lawrence crawls out of the room he cauterizes his wound with a hot pipe, which causes him to lose consciousness. Jigsaw finds him and helps him recover. Afterwards, Jigsaw recruits Lawrence to help him.

Comment: Hey this spoiler text being hidden thing is so awesome :D I didn't know they had that!